# Using FFMEG on NGINX site

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am just beginning to work with servers and HTML and had a question about streaming video.

I was wondering if I setup ffmpeg to create a stream, how can I display that stream on my website?  Can I do that using HTML5?

Will I have to add a module to nginx?  I'm not real sure where to begin but I would rather not use ffserver if I already have a server running.  Thanks.

Comment: I think you need a basic understanding of what it is that you're trying to do.  HTML5 is just a document format, parsed by the browser.  It has nothing to do with what you run server-side.  Nginx is a web server.  FFmpeg is a tool for processing media.  Sure, you can set up Nginx to automatically transcode things but is that really what you're looking for?  As it stands right now, your question is very open-ended.  What is it exactly that you're trying to do?

Comment: I have a webcam that I would like to get a live feed from, then display that on a webpage.  I'm hoping that using ffmpeg I could output to rtmp, then using the video tag display it on a page served from nginx.  But I'm not sure if the tag will be able to use rtmp or if I have to add some other module to nginx to handle the feed and then display with a player or something.

Comment: Ah, that is much more clear, thank you.  Please edit your question to include this information.  Also, how many people are going to be viewing your stream?  If just a couple, WebRTC is the way to go here.  What are your latency requirements?  What browsers are you targeting?  You can serve HLS streams directly from Nginx (or any HTTP server), but it doesn't have the best compatibility at the moment.